# T-SQL "Joining" table to another and collecting top 3 records as columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can't think of a better way to word this.

I have a couple of tables:

```
Postcode | One | Two | Three
2000     |     |     |
2001     |     |     |
2002     |     |     |
```

etc, there's 10,000 postcodes in this table, the `One`, `Two` and `Three` columns are all null.

I have another table like this:

```
Postcode | details
2001     | "foo"
2020     | "bar"
```

Basically, the second table has a select few postcodes, along with some stuff. Let's say there's 2000 postcodes in there.

What I want to do, and I know it's not ideal, is populate the first table's three extra columns, with the postcodes from the second table that are numerically closest to it (whether greater or less).

So far I've done this (BTW my `Postcode` columns are `varchar`):

```
SELECT 
    A.Postcode
    , ( SELECT 
            MAX(X.Postcode)
        FROM (
            SELECT
                CAST(B.Postcode AS INT) AS 'Postcode'
                , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(B.Postcode AS INT) ASC) AS 'rank'
            FROM [TableB] B with(nolock)
            WHERE CAST(B.Postcode AS INT) >= CAST(A.Postcode AS INT)
        ) X WHERE X.[rank] = 1
    ) AS ONE
FROM [TableA] A with(nolock)
```

And this gets me the first postcode that's higher. But I need it to be higher OR lower, and I need three, not just one.

I'm stuck here.

Comment: Could you provide additional data and expected result?

Comment: Order by the absolute value of the difference between postcodes and accept ranks up to 3? Do you want to exclude exact matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of `ROW_NUMBER` and `CROSS APPLY`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/36362/2/0)

```
SELECT
    a.PostCode,
    b.One,
    b.Two,
    b.Three
FROM TableA a
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT
        One = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN x.PostCode END),
        Two = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN x.PostCode END),
        Three = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN x.PostCode END)
    FROM(
        SELECT *, 
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(t.PostCode AS INT))
        FROM(
            SELECT TOP 3 
                PostCode,
                Diff = ABS(CAST(PostCode AS INT) - CAST(a.PostCode AS INT))
            FROM Tableb
            WHERE
                PostCode <> a.PostCode
            ORDER BY ABS(CAST(PostCode AS INT) - CAST(a.PostCode AS INT)), CAST(PostCode AS INT)
        )t
    )x
)b
```

**Result**

```
PostCode   One        Two        Three
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2000       2001       2002       2003
2001       2000       2002       2003
2002       2000       2001       2003
```

---

**Sample Data**

*TableA*

```
PostCode   One        Two        Three
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2000       NULL       NULL       NULL
2001       NULL       NULL       NULL
2002       NULL       NULL       NULL
```

*TableB*

```
PostCode
----------
2000
2001
2002
2003
2004
2005
2006
2007
2008
```